# jQuery-Tabledit throws parseerror "Unexpected end of JSON input" when I edit

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, tabledit

I'm trying to implement jQuery-Tabledit plugin to handle inline table fields editing. The problem is it's that when I edit some fields my console throws a parse error and the data is not updated.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $('#tabla_editable').Tabledit({
            url:'{{route("update_tarea")}}',
            dataType: 'text',
            columns: {
                identifier: [0, 'id'],
                editable: [[1, 'Nombre de Tarea'], [2, 'Descripción de Tarea']]
            },
            onFail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('onFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)');
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            },
            onAjax: function(action, serialize) {
                console.log('onAjax(action, serialize)');
                console.log(action);
                console.log(serialize);
            }
        });
    });
```

The route

```
    Route::post('update','adminProyectoController@update_tareas')->name('update_tarea');
```

And the controller

```
public function update_tareas(Request $request)
{
    \Log::info($request->all());
    //$tarea = Tarea::find($request->input('id'));
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Please help

Thank you

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue and managed to overcome it by checking the response from the server-side and ensuring its valid `JSON` which triggers `onSuccess` instead of `onFail`. I was able to do that by adding `echo json_encode($input);` in my server-side file.

js:

```
$('#data_table').Tabledit({
            deleteButton: true,
            editButton: true,
            restoreButton: false,
            columns: {
              identifier: [0, 'id'],
              editable: [[1, 'col1'], [2, 'col2']]
            },
            hideIdentifier: false,
            url: 'live_edit.php',
            onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert('Updated!');
            },
            onFail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log('Error: ('+textStatus+') '+ errorThrown);
              console.log(jqXHR);
              //alert('Error: ('+textStatus+') '+ errorThrown+' => '+jqXHR);
            },
            onAjax: function(action, serialize) {
                // open your xhr here 
                console.log("on Ajax");
                console.log("action : ", action);
                console.log("data : ", serialize);
            }
          });
```

server code:

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
if ($input['action'] == 'edit') {
    $update_field='';
    if(isset($input['col1'])) {
        $update_field.= "col1='".$input['col1']."'";
    } else if(isset($input['col2'])) {
        $update_field.= "col2='".$input['col2']."'";
    }  

    if($update_field && $input['file_id']) {
        $sql_query = "UPDATE table_nameSET $update_field WHERE id='" . $input['id'] . "'";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql_query) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($con));
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($input);
}
?>
```

Hope this helped.